# detect veritcal swipes over multiple horizontalscrollviews

Tags: android

I have 4 horizontalscrollviews stacked vertically, and they take up the entire screen. I want to be able to detect a vertical swipe down, anywhere on the screen, and perform a specific function when that happens. I have placed an empty layout over the screen that has an onTouchListener, and I detect the downswipe by calculating the start Y position and the endY position, and if it is a certain distance, I call the function.

The problem is with how the views consume touch events. I can only seem to either detect vertical swipe events, or I can scroll the horizontalscrollviews, but I cannot find a solution that allows me to detect both (i.e., if I swipe down, register that, otherwise, let the horizontalscrollviews be moved left/right).

I should note that the horizontalscrollviews are customized, and contain their own ontouchlisteners within themselves, but this shouldn't really matter, as the issue is passing the touch events from the empty layout to the scrollviews, whenever the motion isn't a downward swipe. (please note, I do NOT want to do the calculation on ACTION_UP; if the user keeps their finger down while moving down on the screen, the action should be called, even if they do not lift their finger)

Here is the extracted code I am using to detect touches on the empty layout (as it is now, it is not detecting the downward swipe... but the scrollviews move. If I change the last return statement to true, I can detect down swipes, but then the scrollviews won't move left/right. I assume there must be someway to allow for both?) Thank you for your help!:

```
     touchArea.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
     {
        float startY;
        float startX;

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {

            Log.d(TAG, "in onTouch");

            switch (event.getAction()) 
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    startX = event.getX();
                    startY = event.getY();

                    Log.d(TAG, "action down");
                    Log.d(TAG, "start x is: " + startX + " startY is: " + startY);

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                    Log.d(TAG, "action move");

                    if(event.getY() - startY > MIN_SWIPE_DISTANCE)
                    {
                        Log.d(TAG, "swipe down");

                        //EXECUTE FUNCTION HERE

                        return true;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                    Log.d(TAG, "ACTION UP");

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:

                    Log.d(TAG, "ACTION CANCEL");
                    break;

                default:

                    Log.d(TAG, "unknown touch event");
                    break;

            }

            return false;
        }

    });
```

Comment: Are you saying that changing the last return statement affects whether or not the text "swipe down" is logged? If so, that makes me think that the logic is not as deterministic as is should be.

Comment: Right. As it is now, I will only get the text "action move" once (and no "swipe down" text). In theory, "action move" should be printed every time my finger moves to a new coordinate.